# IdentityServer3 login redirect loop

Tags: asp.net, .net, identityserver3

I have IdentityServer3

When it's working correctly, I have this request after I enter my credentials and it authorizes me to later redirect me to my application:

[image: Request when Login working OK]

Sometimes my users start experiencing a loop inside the login page: They enter credentials, try to login, and the page makes what looks like a postback without any error. When I checked the authorize request, I found that it is completely different from when it's working ok:

[image: Request when looping on Login page]

This stays like this until I recycle IdentityServer3's application pool from IIS console, until, at some point, users start experiencing it again, and I'm not able to reproduce it at will.

Can anyone indicate me what could be the origin for these 2 requests to be this different?

Comment: Can you post more detail about the configuration client and id server you are using?

Comment: Client is a javascript application on browser using the Implicit flow. But still, the problem occurs even when I was trying to only log into the IdServer itself, to the permissions page (where it shows the permissions you gave to apps on the consent screen). So I didn't even really needed to go outside the IdentityServer itself. I could experienced this bug from within it.

Comment: I mean, once the bug occurred, if I don't restart the app pool, I could try to log in from any application and it will keep happening.

Comment: Check https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2496, maybe this can help you.